# Java inline Double condition and unboxing the value crash

Tags: java

Maybe this or similar question has been written already but I managed to create NPE with Java17 in a way I am not too sure is this my or compiler bug even possibly.

The code to reproduce is very simple:

```
Double v1 = null, v2 = null;
Double v3 = v1 != null ? v2 != null ? v1 + v2 : v1 : v2;
```

The code tries to unbox the last `v2` value and I have no idea why there is need to do so at all and not store its value `null` directly as I was expecting it would.

Comment: I'm guessing that `v1 + v2` produces some intermediate `double`, typing the ternary to a `double` "return value", which then unboxes your `v2` in the case that `v1 == null`. Have you tried with a function call that returns `Double`?

Comment: @Rogue you are right, check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of the ternary expression is the common type of each branch. The separate types are `double` for `v1 + v2` and `Double` for `v1` and `v2` separately. Whenever Java combines primitives and their wrappers, it unboxes the wrappers. It doesn't check the target type.

The fix is easy - force `v1 + v2` to be `Double`:

```
Double v3 = v1 != null ? v2 != null ? Double.valueOf(v1 + v2) : v1 : v2;
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer/explanation, it took me quite a while to even understand it where the NPE originated from.